# Usage of ‘each’ with ‘the’

Tags: definite-article

There are pencils labelled A, B and C, and there are people (also labelled A, B and C) who have pencils A, B and C respectively.

Is *Each person has **the** pen* <strike>right</strike> a valid sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the definite article - *the* - when the object is unique, or clearly identifiable. In your example there are three pens, so "*the* pen" doesn't make it clear which one you refer to.

If the three pens belonged to the three people, you could say "each person has *their* pen" (or "their *respective* pen").

If the pens and the people are actually labelled, or identified as "A,B,C" then you could say "each person has *the* pen *that corresponds with their name/identity*".

Comment: The bare assertion *Each person has their pen* sounds just a little odd for the context, but *Each person has **assigned** their pen* sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It isn't a bare assertion, I qualified that this could be used **if** the pens *belonged* to them.

Comment: That's part of the (unspoken?) *context*, not the utterance itself, which is what I was talking about. But my first comment was written wrong - I meant to say *Each person has **their assigned** pen* sounds perfectly natural to me.